# Hex String reading for hash function in java not working

Tags: java, hex, decode, hashcode, parseint

I'm doing a project and i have a really simple hash function in java that *SHOULD* read each "data" (which is a generic type that is a String or Double type read by file) character and make a sum of their values that will be used as hashcode.
I thought that i could convert each character to Hexadecimal, and then "decode" or "parseInt" the obtained String, but it does not work and i do not understand why.

Here is my method:

```
public long HashFunction(T data){
         String bytes = data.toString();

         int value=0;
         for (int i=0; i<bytes.length(); i++) 
             value = value + Integer.decode(Integer.toHexString( bytes.charAt(i) | 0x100000).substring(1)); 

        return (value%1583)%(size);
        //1583 prime number not near to the power of 2, size is the size of the array of my hashtable

    }
```

And here is my error, 0038 should be an "8":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0038"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.decode(Unknown Source)
    at dizionario_package.HashTable.HashFunction(HashTable.java:22)
    at dizionario_package.HashTable.HashInsert(HashTable.java:29)
    at dizionario_package.RecordReader.CreateHTFromFile(RecordReader.java:24)
    at dizionario_package.proviamo.main(proviamo.java:8)
```

Also, i'm sure that the error is in this function, because if i use the java hashcode method, it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the input value for which you are expecting output as 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell `decode` you're using hex. Prefix the string with `0x`.

```
value = Integer.decode("0x"+"10038".substring(1));
```

Comment: IT WORKS, thanks <3
Any suggest to improve the hash function too?

Comment: No problem. Not sure what you want to improve. If it isn't broke don't fix it.